# Change Column Sign Bash

Tags: linux, bash, formatting, format

here my problem. I have a text file organized like this

```
velocity1
List<vector>
1950
(
(-1.60365e-08  0.00686349 1.40107e-08)
(-7.18849e-09  0.0161151  8.25475e-09)
(3.90935e-09   0.0233046 -7.52952e-10)
....
(-1.31565e-09 -0.076973  -1.14286e-11)
(-5.33963e-10  0.0353941 -5.50873e-11)
)
;
```

here the new version i would like to obtain

```
velocity1
List<vector>
1950
(
(-1.60365e-08 -0.00686349 1.40107e-08)
(-7.18849e-09 -0.0161151  8.25475e-09)
(3.90935e-09  -0.0233046 -7.52952e-10)
....
(-1.31565e-09  0.076973  -1.14286e-11)
(-5.33963e-10 -0.0353941 -5.50873e-11)
)
;
```

I would like to change the sign (from positive to negative and viceversa) to the second column maintaining the same format with bash commands. I know the number of elements. Is it possible?

Thanks for help

Comment: please edit your Q to include sample output from the above sample input. You're expected to show your work or research. Please update your Q, rather than respond in comments. Good luck.

Comment: `awk '{$2=$2*-1}1' file > newFile && mv newFile file` . A fragile solution. If you're going to work with this sort of data regularly, `awk` or `python` or `r` would be good languages to have in your tool kit. See http://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html` for a decent intro to `awk`.  Good luck.

Comment: Opps, make that `awk 'NF>2{$2=$2*-1.0}1' file > newFile` The `&& mv NewFile file` is optional and should probably wait until you're certain that you're OK overwriting your original input data. Good luck.